# SpeechRecognitionListener start, stop on separate Thread

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have created a service to handle Speech Recognition. I have created a separate thread (`HandlerThread`) to handle messages when `SpeechRecognitionioListener` run his callbacks. I noticed that after `onResult()` listening is being stopped so tried to call `startListener` in my `Handler` but app crashes, when I call `startListener` from `Activity` bound to `Service`, everything works, but I would like to call `startListener` remotely from service. Is there a possibility to call `startListener()` not from UI thread?

Comment: Post the logcat trace.

Comment: I see that application call SpeechRecognizer.checkIsCalledFromMainThread before startListening

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't run Speech Recognition in a service, it must be run in the main (UI) thread. If you check your error log, you should be able to confirm that this is indeed the show stopper.